# How to export tiff from wms layer?

Tags: qgis

For the purpose of making elevation data for a game which only accept Geotiff images, I wanted to know if there is a way to export a WMS layer into several Geotiff?

I tried to use the save layer function by I have only 1 tiff and a very bad pixelised result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: Thank you Ian 
I'll look to how to fetch data from wcs ^^